# Check if a network is part of bigger network using Python

Tags: python, networking, network-programming

This problem is part of bigger project. Let me start with the project first. That might help in explaining what I want to achieve. The company I work for, has a lot of AWS accounts and these accounts has lot of Security Groups (sg). And hence they have lot of Inbound and Outbound rules. The problem is there are so many rules which overlaps each other.

For example: There is a rule in one sg which allows 10.0.1.0/24 inbound access of port, lets say, 1234. But at the same time there is another rule which allows 10.0.0.0/16 access of all ports. The former rule is clearly not required. Now you can let your imagination go wild and take into consideration other security groups, individual ips, inbound and outbound access and what not.

It would be a nightmare if I had to do this manually. So, I decided to do this programmatically. I am trying my hands with Python scripting these day and this seemed like a perfect place to start. But I am stuck at very first stage. To be able to do this, I think I would need a way to compare three things

- If individual ip or ips are part of a network.
- if a network is part of a bigger network.
- if a port of port range is part of bigger port range.

Googling the first point, showed me several results. I think I will go with ipaddress module. But I am not able to figure out a way to do the 2nd point. I tried being a smart a$$ and experimenting, it didn't succeed.

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> network1 = u'10.0.0.0/16'
>>> ipaddress1 = u'10.0.1.10'
>>> ipaddress.ip_address(ipaddress1) in ipaddress.ip_network(network1)
True
>>>
>>> network2 = u'10.0.1.0/24'
>>> ipaddress.ip_network(network2) in ipaddress.ip_network(network1)
False
>>>
```

So this is what it is. I am hoping I have explained the problem, if not please let me know. I will try and provide more information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And also, I would love to hear how to go about solving this overall project. I think its safe to assume this is a very generic problem.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe you need to explain better: you've got False in the second test - is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `overlaps()`

> overlaps(other)
>
> True if this network is partly or wholly contained in other or other is wholly contained in this network.

```
>>> bigNet = ipaddress.ip_network('10.0.0.0/16')
>>> smallNet = ipaddress.ip_network('10.0.0.0/24')
>>> 
>>> smallNet.overlaps(bigNet)
True
```

But that's not enough since it works both ways:

```
>>> bigNet.overlaps(smallNet)
True
```

So we can check the prefix length too:

```
>>> contains(bigNet,smallNet)
>>> def contains(net1, net2):
    return net1.overlaps(net2) and net1.prefixlen >= net2.prefixlen

>>> contains(bigNet,smallNet)
False
>>> contains(smallNet,bigNet)
True
```

Comment: Thank you. This does it for what I asked.